# Apply coupon code on product collection in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to apply a coupon code on a product collection, but only on the products that meet the conditions. Is this possible?

Current code:

```
<?php
  $_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
  $_productCollection->clear()->addStoreFilter()->load();
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Coupons cann't be applied to products. Coupons can be applied to shopping cart items - quote items. May be you want some coupons to work only if the selected product is in cart?

Comment: Ah, crap. It's supposed to be used on campaign pages (ex. show 8% discount), maybe I'll have to solve it some other way then.